# Suppose Consumer X has read 50 offsets from the topics and it got failed then how consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose Consumer X has read 50 offsets from the topics and it got failed then how consumer  Y will pick up offsets and how does it stores the data and what is the mechanism we need configure to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `enable.auto.commit=true`, and you're not committing offsets yourself, the default commit happens approximately an interval of 500 offsets, as that's the default `max.poll.records`, then a rebalance of the same consumer group will read all the data again.

If you disable auto commits, and/or reduce the max polled records, and manually commit after each batch of records, or per record, then you'll only need to repeat processing the records that came between the last commit and crash

The "data" for offsets is stored in `__consumer_offsets` topic